# Can't create JDBC Connection pool for GlassFish 4.1.1

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, glassfish, connection-pooling

I had downloaded **GlassFish 4.1.1** from official site and trying to create JDBC Connection Pool for **PostgreSQL 9.4** DB on **Windows 8.1**. So what I had done:

1. copied `postgresql-9.4-1200-jdbc41.jar` to `...\glassfish4\glassfish\lib\` (also i tried `...\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\` and `...\glassfish4\javadb\lib\`)
2. opened `http://localhost:4848/` and went to `JDBC` -> `JDBC Connection Pools`
3. pressed `New`, then:

   `Pool Name: PostgreSQLPool
   Resource Type: javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource
   Database Driver Vendor: Postgresql`
4. pressed `Next`

and got:

```
messageInternal Server Error
descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 logs.
```

I have installed JDK 7 & 8. `JAVA_HOME` pointed at `java version "1.7.0_71"` (when I change it to Java 8 nothing happened). In `Path` variable I have both paths to Java 7 & Java 8. I found advises delete `java.exe`, `javax.exe` and etc. from `Windows\System32` and `Windows\SysWOW64` but I haven't these files them.

Log grom GlassFish log file:

```
[2015-10-17T20:00:15.249+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.web.security] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(2)] [timeMillis: 1445104815249] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Context path from ServletContext:  differs from path from bundle: /]]

[2015-10-17T20:00:17.664+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1445104817664] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Redirecting to /common/index.jsf]]

[2015-10-17T20:00:17.810+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=48 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1445104817810] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Admin Console: Initializing Session Attributes...]]

[2015-10-17T20:01:19.134+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.admingui] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1445104879134] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception Occurred :null]]

[2015-10-17T20:02:32.379+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=106 _ThreadName=admin-listener(6)] [timeMillis: 1445104952379] [levelValue: 900] [[
  StandardWrapperValve[FacesServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet FacesServlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:851)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.createPartialResponseWriter(PartialViewContextImpl.java:504)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.access$300(PartialViewContextImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$DelayedInitPartialResponseWriter.getWrapped(PartialViewContextImpl.java:642)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startDocument(PartialResponseWriter.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:127)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doChainInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:678)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]
```

Comment: A response output stream has nothing with connection pooling, look at your title.

Comment: @RomanC It seems to be a bug in the Connection pool configuration module of Glassfish 4.1.